# NestJS: How to customise log messages to include request id and name of the file the log message occurred

Tags: logging, nestjs, winston, nestjs-config, nest-winston

I am new to NestJS and would like to customise the log messages to include the x-request-id/x-correlation-id and the name of the file the log message originated but am not sure if there is anything in NestJS to do that.

My application is using NestJS with the Fastify adapter and has the following configuration in the bootstrap() function

```js
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
    {
        logger: WinstonModule.createLogger(winston.createLogger({
          exitOnError: false,
          level: 'debug',
          handleExceptions: true,
          format: winston.format.combine(
            winston.format.timestamp(),
            winston.format.ms(),
            winston.format.colorize(),
            winston.format.align(),
            winston.format.splat(),
            winston.format.printf((info) => {
                return `${info.timestamp} [ ${info.level} ] : ${info.message}`;
            }),
          ),
          transports: [
            new (winston.transports.Console)()
          ]
        }),
      )
    }
  );
```

This seems to format the logs using winston as expected.

`2022-03-09T11:21:22.131Z [ info ] :     Starting Nest application...`

However, I would also like to include the request/correlation id in the message and the name of the file the log message occurred e.g.

`2022-03-09T11:21:22.131Z 2cfd4eee-ca2b-4869-b66b-2b7da291f567 [ info ] [ Main.ts ]:     Starting Nest application...`

Is there anything in NestJS itself to allow this or any external libraries that I could use to achieve the desired result ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to get it working using the [nest-pino](https://github.com/iamolegga/nestjs-pino) library:

```js
// main.ts

import { Logger } from 'nestjs-pino';

async function bootstrap() {

const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
    { bufferLogs: true }
  );

  app.useLogger(app.get(Logger));
  
}
bootstrap();
```

```js
// app.module.ts

import { LoggerModule } from 'nestjs-pino';

@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      pinoHttp: {
        level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'debug',
        redact: ['request.headers.authorization'],
        prettyPrint: {
          colorize: true,
          singleLine: true,
          levelFirst: false,
          translateTime: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.l'Z'",
          messageFormat: "{req.headers.x-correlation-id} [{context}] {msg}",
          ignore: "pid,hostname,context,req,res,responseTime",
          errorLikeObjectKeys: ['err', 'error']
        }
      }
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [MyController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
// my.controller.ts
import { Controller, Get, Param, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller()
export class MyController {
    private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(MyController.name);

    @Get('/:id')
    async getCustomerDetails(@Headers() headers, @Param('id') id: string): Promise<Customer> {
        this.logger.log(`Accepted incoming request with id: ${id}`);

        // Do some processing ....

        return customer;
    }
}
```

```js
[2022-11-14T11:03:07.100Z] INFO: 428f0df9-d12b-4fca-9b11-805a13ff41be [MyController] Accepted incoming request with id: 1
```

****** UPDATE **********

I also managed to update the redacted fields to be configurable from a .yaml file

```js
// app.module.ts

import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { LoggerModule } from 'nestjs-pino';

@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        pinoHttp: {
          level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info',
          redact: configService.get<string[]>('logger.redacted.fields'),
          prettyPrint: {
            colorize: false,
            singleLine: true,
            levelFirst: false,
            translateTime: "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss.l'Z'",
            messageFormat: '{req.headers.x-correlation-id} [{context}] {msg}',
            ignore: 'pid,hostname,context,req,res,responseTime',
            errorLikeObjectKeys: ['err', 'error'],
          },
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [MyController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

dev.yaml

```
logger:
    redacted:
        fields:
            - 'headers.Authorization'
            - 'headers["X-Api-Key"]'
```

****** FURTHER UPDATE ******

This article on medium also describes how to add correlation ids to log messages with winston

https://medium.com/@jose-luis-navarro/logging-on-nestjs-like-a-pro-with-correlation-ids-log-aggregation-winston-morgan-and-more-d03e3bb56772

Comment: The above answer is correct. 
But if anyone wants to use Pino as their logger and not the default Logger provided by NestJS, then add the below line in the constructor of your controller or provider:

`@InjectPinoLogger(MyController.name)
 private readonly logger: PinoLogger `

Now simply using `this.logger.info({msg: 'controller data'})` would work like a charm.

Comment: Hi there, I want add same request id for typeorm log. How can I do this? Because I just want to get all log of a request (process controller, data and orm log as well)

Answer (score 6):

1. Assign a request ID. Make this your first `middleware`.
2. Bind the request context with `logger`. Make a class of `Logger`, bind the `request context` to logger. It will act basically as wrapper for `WinstonLogger`. Override all the methods of winston logger to print the request ID in form an manner which you want (preferred way is using JSON as it will be easier for you to query in logs).

Comment: Underrated answer

Comment: Do you mind providing a snipped on how to do this: "Make a class of Logger, bind the request context to logger." ? :)

Comment: @DanielEberl some of the snippets are here: https://github.com/Adityagaddhyan/logger-snippet-node

They are in JS but you can write your own on same lines in NestJS or TS. Nest has library function for request context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using winston,

Use logFormatter from winston to add more fields to each logs:-

One example below:

```
const { format} = require("winston");
var reqId = '123123' //function or const request id
const addRequestId = format((info, opts) => {
    if(reqId)
        info.reqId= reqId;
    return info;
});
```

Then add below config while creating logger

```
var config = {
format: format.combine(
  addRequestId(),
  format.timestamp(new Date().toISOString()),
  format.json(),
),
transports: [new transports.Console()],
level: 'debug'
 }
const logger = createLogger(config);
```

To get file name, use (new Error()).trace property. This will give you full stack trace containing file names and line number in each file.